# c programming help in strcmp of struct char array

Tags: c, sorting, struct

program automatically exits at this point, so i presume the mistake is on this code:

```
 for(k=0; k<cc; k++){
     smallest = k;
     for(j=k+1; j<cc; j++){
         if (strcasecmp(pb[k].name, pb[j].name)>0){
                smallest = j;
         }
     }
     swapString(pb[k].name, pb[j].name);
  }
```

the following are my initial declarations:

```
void swapString(char string1[], char string2[]){
    char temp[31];
    strcpy(temp, string1);
    strcpy(string1, string2);
    strcpy(string2, temp);
}

typedef struct myphonebook{
char name[31];
char address[101];
char cellphone[11];
char email[21];
} Myphonebooktype;

int main (int argc, char * argv[]){
Myphonebooktype*pb = NULL;

FILE*fp;

char username[16];
char password[16];
char option;
int i, k, j, cc, smallest;
```

is strcmp wrong? or i cannot compare strings inside struct?
my goal is to sort my struct alphabetically. 
update: sorry, my mistake, it should be k

Comment: In your `for` loop which says `for(k=0; i<cc; k++){` did you mean to use `i` rather than `k`? I.e. did you mean `for(k=0; k<cc; k++){`

Comment: You don't even use the value of `smallest`.

Comment: `swapString(pb[k].name, pb[j].name);` meant `swapString(pb[0..cc-1].name, pb[cc].name);,`

Comment: tnx, you're also correct, i should have used the smallest when i used the swap function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple typo in your outer `for` loop:

```
for(k=0; i<cc; k++){
```

Should be `k<cc` I think? This error is probably causing an "infinite loop," but as soon as `k` reaches `cc` you're indexing past the end of the array, which is undefined behavior (explains your program crashing).